# Could not find or load main class with a Jar File.The cause is a bcprov-jdk15-133

Tags: java, jar, signature

Execute jar shows Could not find or load main class with a Jar File.
Before I add some 3rd jar to project, it's ok. Then I add and delete repeatedly, finally confirm It's bcprov-jdk15-133.jar.
Why can't jar execute after I add this package?
[e](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUPC5.png)
As shown in the figure, the left's can execute. The main different is the 3rd package. When I delete the BCKEY.SF BCKEY.DSA and it could execute.So it's the jar sign problem. But I don't know how to deal it.

Comment: Do you have a manifest file within your project which specifies which one is the main class? Normally, if you create a jar package using an IDE such as intellij IDEA, it will ask you what the main class is and create the manifest accordingly.

Comment: not the reason.

Comment: Okay. Can you please post the code here and list the dependencies? It’s just the main class with few other classes probably, correct? If yes, then please post it here, so we can help you further. If you keep saying “not the reason” for comments made by everyone without posting what happens when you try that particular soluton, it just discourages us and helps neither you or us. We are here to resolve your problem.

Comment: Oh. Got the link to the code from your question itself. It had just the one letter (e) with the link. :) Thanks @Z.BB

Comment: Nope. That’s not the link. It points to some image. Can you please post a link to your code?

Answer (score 0):

JAR files contains manifest file that specifies the main class to execute with the command:

```
java -jar jarfile
```

Mainfest file entry:

```
Main-Class: com.test.something.Executable
```

The JAR file is an executable without specifying main class to run, as manifest entry would be picked by default.
But in case this is not specified and their are multiple main classes in the same archive, execution would fail. So,

1. Update the manifest to add the main-class entry
   or
2. Execute JAR file with command to exeucte the main method in this class

   **java -cp jarfile com.test.something.Executable**